# Cannot get a JavaFX frame into my swing application

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a java swing project that I creating and basically I am going to use JavaFX to simplify to creation of a pie chart to display some data for users. I have created the class that I wish to use to accomplish this by extending JFXPanel and then initiating and adding it into the swing JFrame like so

```
JFXPanel piePanel = new PieChartSample(test);
contentPane.add(piePanel);
piePanel.setVisible(true);
```

In this case, test is an arbitary array of ints.

I suspect the issue is not here but in the PieChartSample Code although this is lengthy and not so clear.

```
public class PieChartSample extends JFXPanel{

ArrayList<Integer> vals;

public PieChartSample(ArrayList<Integer> vals) {
this.vals = vals;
}

private static void initAndShowGUI() {
// This method is invoked on the EDT thread
JPanel frame = new JPanel();
final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(fxPanel);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initFX(fxPanel);
    }
   });
}

private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
// This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
Scene scene = createScene();
fxPanel.setScene(scene);
}

private static Scene createScene() {
Group  root  =  new  Group();
Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
Text  text  =  new  Text();


ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new PieChart.Data("%0", 22),
        new PieChart.Data("%20", 13),
        new PieChart.Data("%40", 25),
        new PieChart.Data("%60", 10),
        new PieChart.Data("%80", 22),
        new PieChart.Data("%100", 30));
final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");

((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);

root.getChildren().add(text);

return (scene);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initAndShowGUI();
    }
});
}
}
```

Basically when I start the JFrame the JFXPanel does not show at all. Any ideas?

Comment: The only issue that I can see in your code is that `JPanel frame = new JPanel();` should be `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`